# Длинное условие в Python. Too many boolean expressions in if statement (6/5)

Tags: python, if, условия

Подскажите пожалуйста, как грамотно писать длинные условия.
После ввода данного условия:

```
if m1[1] >= 1 or m2[1] >= 1 or m3[1] >= 1 or p4[1] >= 1 or m5[1] >= 1 or m6[1] >= 1:
    with open(r"C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\My_projects\Birji\istok.txt",'a') as fileistok:
```

Python выдаёт ошибку:

> Too many boolean expressions in if statement (6/5)

Comment: Но ведь это не ошибка, а предупреждение, так?

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо за поправку. Но из-зи этого предупреждения код через раз выдавал ошибку,  связанную с обнаружением среза m1[1] .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На скорую руку можно так, например:

```
data =  [m1[1], m2[1], m3[1], p4[1], m5[1], m6[1]]
if any([x for x in data if x >= 1]):
    with open(....
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

```
if any(m[1] >= 1 for m in [m1, m2, m3]):
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае нужно использовать all, в зависимости от того, сколько или какие элементы вам нужно проверить

```
all(item >=1 for (_, _, item) in m1)
```

Comment: тут несколько проблем. Во-первых, в вопросе ``or``, а у вас ``and``. Во вторых, в вопросе 6 списков, а у вас один.